# jQuery keeping track of page content and resize accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this:

```
function fixContainer() {
    $('div#mainContainer').css({
        'min-height': $(document).height() - 104 // -104 is for a fixed header.. nvm that.
    }).removeShadow().dropShadow({
        'blur' : 5,
        'opacity' : 0.2
    });
}
```

works pretty good, but sometimes in the future content will load using ajax and jquery templates. This does not fire. How can I make mainContainer have the 100% height at all times?

### forgot to mention the following:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    fixContainer();
});
```

Comment: Can you show some code of you ajax call ? 
When does your code work (before/after what action) ?

Comment: Hi Marc, ajax is just a simple post request that will populate a jquery template file with the returned json object. nothing fancy there. On initial page load the code works fine, but when the new template is appended I can't fix the mainContainer height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    fixContainer();
});
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I should have seen this one. `$(document).height()` stays the same on a resize. You want `$(window).height()`

Comment: :/ thanks for the help man. Even that is still rendering the same way.

Comment: hmmm... in a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fhNTv/

but i do get an error for removeShadow... did you write/import that?

Comment: this is a plugin that I am using... I can't remember where I've got it from. but works quite well. I am trying to keep the shadow on the element when its height changes. But can't seem to detect that change automatically and redraw the elements

Comment: Why not just use CSS box-shadow? It follows the DIV dynamically. Updated the JSfiddle

Comment: well because this is a css3 property and is not supported by IE8-

Comment: accepted because I ended up using css3... People should upgrade already.

Comment: Damn straight. You could also do browser detection with $.browser.msie and render maybe a less fluid version for people who keep reviving their Win98 machines